# How to resolve rq multiple tasks h12 heroku timeout?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, redis

I am trying to run a heroku flask python application with redis. However, I am facing the following error:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/uploaderlocal" host=a2n.herokuapp.com dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=31890ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

The heroku web page crashes with the above error(due to a timeout), but the background processes will continue to run. Is there any possible way to stall the heroku web page until the tasks in the redis background queue have finished? Below is my code for your reference. Note that I am trying to finish multiple redis queued tasks before I return the results.html template.

```
from rq import Queue

from worker import conn

from rq.job import Job
app = Flask(__name__)
q = Queue(connection=conn)

job1 = q.enqueue_call(func=method1(), args=(), timeout='1h')

job2 = q.enqueue_call(func=method2(), args=(), timeout='1h')

job3 = q.enqueue_call(func=method3(), args=(), timeout='1h')

job4 = q.enqueue_call(func=method4(), args=(), timeout='1h')

the below code attempts (but fails) to stall the return of the #html template before the processes are finished

while(len(q)>0):

time.sleep(1)

return render_template('result.html')
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify my question. I am asking if there is a way to check when the redis queue tasks have successfully completed so that I can appropriately proceed once all of the queued tasks are finished.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have some spaces in front of the time.sleep(1) command?

The value of the variable q will not change at any time inside the while loop. Therefore it will permanently sleep, or exit straight out.

You need to re-evaluate q in the while loop, possibly as follows:

```
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        q = Queue(connection=conn)
        if len(q) == 0:      
            break
```

Comment: According to https://python-rq.org/docs/ You are checking the length of the q correctly, but you are checking in the wrong place in your program. You are checking the length before you add anything to the q, so the value of q in your code will always be zero.